# nm-applet running, indicator not in taskbar- new behavior in 16.04

Tags: network-manager, indicator, lxpanel, panel-applets

On Lubuntu 16.04, within the last week the nm-applet indicator disappeared from the taskbar even tho LXTask shows it running, and the wifi connection works as usual. The missing indicator is a new behavior- it has run fine for ~6 months since OS install.  At first look, nm-applet was not in LXSession core applications and when I clicked Reload, the indicator came back on the panel for a couple hours, then it disappeared again. I went back to LXSession, reloaded again (no change); then manually added it to startup appl's + reboot - no joy.

After reading here, I edited `/home/*****/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` .
`NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;` also had `LXDE;`. I removed `LXDE;`, saved, + reboot - no change.

In terminal `$ nm-applet` returns:

```
** (nm-applet:#####): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus 
address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name 
org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

`#####` is a 4 or 5 digit number which gets higher when I do the command again.

`$ sudo nm-applet` returns the above, plus:

```
(nm-applet:#####): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: 
assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
```

I tried reinstalling `lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin`.  I've found posts suggesting installing other network monitor or indicator packages + have tried several, with no success.  But the indicator worked fine for many months, LXTask shows nm-applet running, something removed nm-applet from LXSession, and added LXDE to `NotShowIn` in 'autostart/nm-applet.desktop`.  These things suggest the answer is more likely to be fixing nm-applet, indicator, or environment, rather than adding something else. I have read there was a bug with nm-applet in 14.04 but that appears to be fixed a year or more ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things fixed this.

1. This error:

> ** (nm-applet:#####): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

... was fixed by installing `at-spi2-core` from Synaptic Package Manager.
Reference: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/16327

2. Then in `/etc/xdg/autostart/nmapplet.desktop`, I changed `Exec=nm-applet`
   to `dbus-launch nm-applet`.
   After manually restarting nm-applet in a terminal window with `dbus-launch nm-applet`, the wifi indicator applet appeared in the taskbar again.  But it did not autostart after a reboot.
3. So in Settings > Default Applications for LX Session, in the Autostart tab, I changed `nm-applet` to `dbus-launch nm-applet`.

Then the applet autostarted, and the indicator autostarted.

Reference for 2. and 3. : 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/592406/nm-applet-wifi-issues-on-lubuntu-14-04