# Lubuntu 18.04 keyring (dbus) not working

Tags: 18.04, lxde, dbus, keyrings, seahorse

After updating from 16.04 to 18.04, GNOME3 is to slow on my hardware (2010 dual core, 4GB, 128GB SSD)

So I decided to switch to Lubuntu, way faster.

All fine, except:
there seems to be no password manager/keyring. So I installed seahorse and libpam-gnome-keyring.

Doesn't work, a terminal is still asking every time in the terminal for my ssh passwords. I can do `ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa`, but that will save the password only for terminal programs, not for the file-manager.

How do i get the Ubuntu behavior asking a passphrase once in a GUI dialog and saving it for the session for GUI programs and terminal?

It must be a LXDE config issue, all packages are there even when lubuntu-desktop is installed next to Ubuntu, it won't work using the lubuntu-environment.

```
journalctl | grep -i gnome-keyring-daemon

gnome-keyring-daemon[890]: couldn't set environment variable in session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, '(ss)', does not match expected type '(s)'
```

Starting seahorse

```
(seahorse:1488): dbind-WARNING **: 08:36:27.966: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

Answer (score 1):

At least the last error should be fixed by following the steps explained on this page: [nm-applet running, indicator not in taskbar- new behavior in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938442/nm-applet-running-indicator-not-in-taskbar-new-behavior-in-16-04)
For me (on Lubuntu 18.04) just installing the package `at-spi2-core` sufficed to get rid of this problem.

Seahorse is indeed made for Nautilus, but I found on https://forum.antergos.com/topic/1132/the-file-manager-pcmanfm-doesn-t-remember-passwords/5 the suggestion to install `lxpolkit` (or try `polkit-gnome`) and to make it start up automatically.
You can do this by using the non-GUI approach that is explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/575262
It states that you should add a .desktop file to `~/.config/autostart` with a content like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<Name of application as displayed>
Exec=<command to execute>
Icon=<full path to icon>
Comment=<optional comments>
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Does this work in your case?

Comment: Thx, I also found a hint for that package already somewhere else, yes installing that removes the error message but not the problem: a password request in a shell does not open a GUI box.

Comment: @Janghou I edited my answer.

Comment: lxpolkit is already installed, and running, also polkitd. It is also working for Krusader and PCMANFM. Asking once. For terminal I seem to do `ssh-add` manually once. That's OK, but I can't understand that a password (keyring) feature is missing from a default Lubuntu install. Hope this will be fixed for 18.10. LXQt is really promising, (with some KDE programs)